# Defining Functions to be Passed Around as Arguments

Tags: javascript, function

Alright, so I've been looking at functions and using them as arguments. Let's say I have a function that takes a function and does it:

```
function run(someFunction,someArgument) {
    someFunction(someArgument);
}
```

I see that I can pass an existing function, say:

```
function foo(bar) {
    // foo that bar!
}
```

By calling `run(foo,bar);` I can also make up a function in an object on the fly and run it:

```
var whiteBoy = {
    playThat: function(funkyMusic) {
        // funk out in every way
    }
};
```

And then I call `run(whiteBoy.playThat,funkyMusic);` What I'd like to be able to do is define a function in the call, like this:

```
run(/* define a new function */,relevantArgument);
```

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
run(function(funkyMusic) {
    // funk out in every way
}, relevantArgument);
```

You were very close when you wrote this:

```
var whiteBoy = {
    playThat: function(funkyMusic) {
        // funk out in every way
    }
};
```

What you did there was define a function and assign it to the `playThat` property - the only change that I made was to define a function and pass it as an argument instead of assigning it to something.

Answer (score 2):

```
run(function(when)
   { 
      alert("play that funky music " + when);
   },
  "noooow!");
```